# Dresden Files - balancing for pre-modern periods

Tags: balance, fate, dresden-files

I'm trying to build a Dresden Files campaign set during the French Revolution (using the Dresden Files 2010 RPG rules).

First issue I had to solve was that wizards-technology incompatibility doesn't yet exist. I remember Butcher mentioned in one of the books that at some time period, wizards used to have problems with skin disease, so I went with that. (This also connected to Jean-Paul Marat, so it fit nicely with the setting.)

However, then I ran into a problem: in a Dresden campaign set in modern times, a Vanilla Human has access to guns, which even out the field quite a bit, and to cars (you can ram a monster with one), and to all kinds of other useful technology. French-revolution period guns were slow and imprecise compared to modern weapons, and while ability to use a sword was much more common, supernatural beings would have super-strength, or super-speed, or some such advantage making fights rather one-sided.

With that in mind, **what advantage can I give humans in the 18th century, so they won't be drastically and painfully under-powered?**  I want to maintain "Mere Mortal" playable, without a player choosing it feeling like "the load" on the party.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You likely won't have a problem.

The Dresden FATE rules don't account for as much of a gap between human capability and the Supernatural as there is in the books. Your average Murphy (with some Refresh put into Stunts) can keep up with a young Raith.

Furthermore, guns aren't nearly as powerful in RPG terms as they are in real life. See page 202 of Volume 1: Your Story which includes a table that:

- Equates "belly gun" firearms to knives (Attack:1)
- Equates pistols to one handed swords and baseball bats (Attack:2)
- Equates Desert Eagles and long guns to two handed swords (Attack:3)

A Mere Mortal could pick a similar weapon of choice and keep up with Inuhuman Strength (damage +2) just as well as in 2010.

### A Side Note on 'Technology'

One thing that could help make the campaign more engaging is have magic interfere with something else. Note [this reference](http://dresdenfiles.wikia.com/wiki/Magic#cite_ref-DF14ch19_13-0) (9.0) from Cold Days:

> It used to be magic caused dairy products to spoil and warts and boils appear on the human skin.

Magic always interferes with *modern* technology, whether that be archaic medicine, pasteurization, or electricity. Find something from the late 1700's that would be really inconvenient to the Wizards to not have, and say it affects *that*.

---

For permanency, @[Blechpirat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/28892/blechpirat)'s awesome comment:

> You could also vary the amount of knowledge the public has about the supernatual, esp. warding techniques. Since these guys are much closer to the dark ages, they probably have a lot of folklore that actually works - making it easier to guess vulnerabilites or being able to ward of magic. But don't overdo it, I agree that the game does not need any tweaking on the mechanical side. But what you need is a way to let non-wizards shine. Which is usually using computers etc. In your setting a wizard should have areas where he or she can not be better then a mortal.

Comment: You could also vary the amount of knowledge the public has about the supernatual, esp. warding techniques. Since these guys are much closer to the dark ages, they probably have a lot of folklore that actually works - making it easier to guess vulnerabilites or being able to ward of magic. But don't overdo it, I agree that the game does not need any tweaking on the mechanical side. 

But what you need is a way to let non-wizards shine. Which is usually using computers etc. In your setting a wizard should have areas where he or she can not be better then a mortal.